# How can you use a healing surge during battle?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, actions, healing

In the PHB it says:

> Even in a heated battle, you can heal. You can heal yourself by using your second wind (see page 291), an ally can use the Heal skill (see page 185) on you, and an ally can use a healing power on you.

But I want to know if there is a way to just use a healing surge as a standard action.(by the book)
Can you just use a healing surge without it being triggered by any of the above stated actions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only having one second wind means that a player has to come up with different ways to use those healing surges during battle, which makes having powers, items, or feats that let you or your allies spend healing surges more valuable (*healing strike* or *healer's mercy* anyone?).  Alternatively **a group can just have two leaders**. The leader classes usually come with a couple extra healing surge related powers in addition to their twice/encounter standard healing.

Comment: @Mark Rogers Or have one of the leaders multi-class into another leader class... >_> .. <_<

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No, something must trigger the use of a healing surge**

In order to use a healing surge, something has to trigger it. The main triggers are going to be Second Wind and healing powers. There isn't a way to just "spend a healing surge".

Note that the Heal skill can allow you to use a Second Wind without spending an action to do so, but it does not allow you to spend a healing surge (without having your Second Wind available).

You can also use Potions to spend a healing surge in order to heal yourself, by spending a minor action to drink, and getting a static value back based on the potion.

Answer (score 5):

No, those are the only mechanisms, barring peculiar and explicit exceptions granted by other powers or items.

See also the Rules Compendium, p. 258:

> Most healing requires a character to spend a healing surge.  […] 
>   Once per encounter, a character can use the second wind action to spend a healing surge and regain hit points.

The only way to spend a healing surge on your own during combat is with a Power or with a second wind.

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that the basic answer is "Yes", not "No".
However, the mechanism is a Healing potion, or healing fruit etc.  While technically this is a "no" answer, for most players, I don't think they think of healing potions as a "healing power", "healing skill", or "second wind".  However, technically, the Healing potion activates a "Healing power" inherent in the potion.

Answer (score 1):

Using a healing surge as a standard action is the entire point of the second wind action. The once-per-encounter limit serves as a reasonable limit on how much time you can spend (or waste) extending your useful capacity for tanking damage in a given fight. Every turn spent not making an attack is a turn added to the combat, which can wear on everyone at the table and come across as unfun.

The most reliable, gear-independent, class-independent, and party-independent way to extend your hit point value and burn through surges in a fight, if you still feel the need to, is to use the Endurance skill power *Third Wind*, either in place of one of your utility powers or from taking the Skill Power feat, found in *Player's Handbook 3*. (*Third Wind* allows you to use a minor action to spend a healing surge, once between extended rests.)